# How to fix overwrites when adding objects to a List

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to add objects to a list to be accessed other places in a program. However, whenever I add a new object all previous objects are then turned into copies of the most recently added object.

I tried first using a loop to loop through objects, but found that when adding a new object it overwrote all other objects that were already in the list. I have done some looking around and I think it has something to do with referencing objects in memory. However I don't know how to fix the referencing.

```
    List <ObjectTester> holder = new List<ObjectTester>();
    //for(int i =0; i<5; i++)
    //{
    //    ObjectTester objec = new ObjectTester(i.ToString());
    //    holder.Add(objec);
    //    foreach (ObjectTester o in holder)
    //    {
    //        Console.WriteLine(o.ToString());
    //    }
    //}
    holder.Add(new ObjectTester("01"));
    Console.WriteLine(holder[0]);
    holder.Add(new ObjectTester("02"));
    Console.WriteLine(holder[0]);
    Console.WriteLine(holder[1]);
```

```
public class ObjectTester
{
    private static string id;

    public ObjectTester(string _id)
    {
        id = _id;
    }
}
```

When doing the commented portion and displaying with a loop I expect to see
`0 1 2 3 4`
However it prints out as 
`4 4 4 4 4`
because all the previous values are changed. 
To test this I printed the values after adding them to the list and the output was:
`0 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4`
showing me that it was overriding with every new addition to the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because your id in your ObjectTester class is static.

Remove the static keyword. Check out the MS documentation on the static keyword: [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)

It's not overriding the object. It's overriding the id field because since it is marked static, it does not belong to a specific instance of the ObjectTester class.

Comment: that makes so much sense! And yep, it's doing what I expected now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem buddy :)